# Загрузка скрипта из сайта в случае неудачи при загрузке из googleapis.com

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать проверку: если скрипт не загрузился с `googleapis.com`, сделать загрузку скрипта с моего сайта?

Загрузить jquery c googleapis.com:

```
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

В случае неудачи загрузить с моего сайта:

```
<script src="./jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: используй [событие onerror](https://learn.javascript.ru/onload-onerror)

Comment: а в чём смысл загружать скрипт с другого сайта, если он уже есть на твоём?

Comment: @norbornen Не с другого сайта а с серверов `googleapis.com`.

Comment: судя по тексту вопроса у тебя есть jquery.min.js на твоём сайте. исходя из этого в чём выгода его загрузки с googleapis.com? исходя из того, что у тебя с googleapis.com он может не загружаться - тем более в чём выгода?

Comment: @norbornen Я с тобой согласен , но хостинг на котором сайт, когда много пользователей на сайте, начинает тупить, а  если подключить через гугл , меньшая нагрузка на хостинг и сайт лучше работает.

Comment: ну тогда повесь на `<script>` обработчик `onerror` и внутри него в `<head>` аттач загрузку библиотеки с другого ресурса. только учти, что если ты используешь обработчики onload/ondomload то они запустятся раньше, чем ты получишь библиотеку повторным запросом

Comment: @norbornen Может с большой вероятностью получится так, что jQuery с гугловой CDN уже использовался на других сайтах, которые пользователь посещал. Тогда библиотека осела в кэш браузера и браузер вместо качания по сети сразу воспользуется закэшированным вариантом.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write(
        '<script src="./jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>');
</script>
```